# Represent a hierarchical data.frame as a nested list

Tags: regex, r, recursion

How to nicely convert a data.frame with hierarchical information to a JSON (or nested list)?

Let's say we have the following data.frame:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = c('1', '1.1', '1.1.1', '1.2'), 
  value = c(10, 5, 5, 5)) 

#  id   value
#     1    10
#   1.1     5
# 1.1.1     5
#   1.2     5
```

Then I would like to end up with the following JSON:

```
{
 "id": "1",
 "value": 10,
 "children": [
  {
   "id": "1.1",
   "value": 5,
   "children": [
    {
     "id": "1.1.1", 
     "value": 5 
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "id": "1.2",
   "value": 5
  }
 ]
}
```

Where `id` defines the hierarchical structure, and `.` is a delimiter.

My intention is to easily be able to convert data from R to hierarchical D3 visualisations (e.g. [Partition Layout](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/partition.html) or [Zoomable Treemaps](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/treemap/)). It would also be nice if it is possible to add more "value"-columns; e.g `value`, `size`, `weight`, etc.

Thank you!

***EDIT:** I reverted to the original question, so it is easier to follow all the answers (sorry for all the editing).*

Comment: have you looked at the `rjson` package?

Comment: or the `RJSONIO` package?

Answer (score 3):

I tend to have `RJSONIO` installed which does this:

```
R> df <- data.frame(id = c('1', '1.1', '1.1.1', '1.2'), value = c(10, 5, 5, 5)) 
R> RJSONIO::toJSON(df)
[1] "{\n \"id\": [ \"1\", \"1.1\", \"1.1.1\", \"1.2\" ],\n\"value\": [     10,      5,      5,      5 ] \n}"
R> cat(RJSONIO::toJSON(df), "\n")
{
 "id": [ "1", "1.1", "1.1.1", "1.2" ],
"value": [     10,      5,      5,      5 ] 
} 
R>
```

That is *not* your desired output but the desired nesting / hierarchy was *not* present in the data.frame.  I think if you nest a data.frame inside a list you will get there.

**Edit:** For your revised question, here is the R output of reading you spec'ed JSON back in:

```
R> RJSONIO::fromJSON("/tmp/foo.json")
$id
[1] "1"

$value
[1] 10

$children
$children[[1]]
$children[[1]]$id
[1] "1.1"

$children[[1]]$value
[1] 5

$children[[1]]$children
$children[[1]]$children[[1]]
$children[[1]]$children[[1]]$id
[1] "1.1.1"

$children[[1]]$children[[1]]$value
[1] 5




$children[[2]]
$children[[2]]$id
[1] "1.2"

$children[[2]]$value
[1] 5



R>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, but how do I deal with the hierarchical structure? E.g. that `1.1.1` is the child of `1.1`. In my case the `id` column represent sections.

Comment: That is an R question of representation, no a JSON conversion question.  But if you know JSON, you could ... spec a json data object and call `RJSONIO::fromJSON()` on it!

Comment: Yep, you are right. My question is rather how to represent the data.frame (or just df$id) as nested list instead. Then it's probably better to convert the list to JSON with `RJSONIO`. (I will edit the question)

Comment: Wow. So now we are at version three of the question, and all references to JSON have been dropped.  Are you going to switch programming languages next?  ;-)   I'm done here, what you have is a relatively simple R programming exercise. It would help if you had more structure in your input data, but I'll be the last one to suggest you edit your question. Again.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution.

First I define the following functions:

```
# Function to get the number hierarchical dimensions (occurences of "." + 1)
ch_dim <- function(x, delimiter = ".") {
    x <- as.character(x)
    chr.count <- function(x) length(which(unlist(strsplit(x, NULL)) == delimiter))
    if (length(x) > 1) {
        sapply(x, chr.count) + 1
    } else {
        chr.count(x) + 1
    }
}

# Function to convert a hierarchical data.frame to a nested list
lst_fun <- function(ch, id_col = "id", num = min(d), stp = max(d)) {

    # Convert data.frame to character
    ch <- data.frame(lapply(ch, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

    # Get number of hierarchical dimensions
    d <- ch_dim(ch[[id_col]])

    # Convert to list
    lapply(ch[d == num,][[id_col]], function(x) {
        tt <- ch[grepl(sprintf("^%s.", x), ch[[id_col]]),]
        current <- ch[ch[[id_col]] == x,]
        if (stp != num && nrow(tt) > 0) { 
            c(current, list(children = lst_fun(tt, id_col, num + 1, stp)))
        } else { current }
    })
}
```

then convert the data.frame to a list:

```
lst <- lst_fun(df, "id")
```

and finally, the JSON:

```
s <- RJSONIO::toJSON(lst)
```